# I am getting this error : Key Error: 'text'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting error at `df['text']=df['text'].map(lambda x: ....)`. Kindly help. So, i am making a lstm and getting this keyerror(as defined in title). 
Any help is really appreciated.

```
import nltk
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

np.random.seed(7)
df = pd.read_csv('financial.csv')

def clean(text):
    text=text.translate(string.punctuation)
    text=text.lower().split()
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    text = [w for w in text if not w in stops and len(w) >= 3]
    text = text.split()
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
    stemmed_words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text]
    text = " ".join(stemmed_words)
    return text

df['text'] = df['text'].map(lambda text: clean(text))
```

Comment: It means there is no column `text`, what return `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Please format your code properly, and remember that in Python indentation is important. And please show us an example of your input file. Also always copy-paste the actual error, in full and complete, into the question body, and mark out the line where it happens (with e.g. a comment). Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [thos Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

A Python KeyError exception is what is raised when you try to access a key that isn’t in a dictionary (dict). Most likely, `df['text']` doesn't always exist as a key. What you might want to do is use a try/except:

```
try:
    df['text'] = df['text'].map(lambda text: clean(text))

except KeyError:
    "Whatever you want it to do if it doesn't find a 'text' key in the df dictionary"
```

Hope that helps and have a nice day :)